# Force all Azure access through Management Groups

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-rbac, azure-management-groups

We are looking to force all Azure access assignments to go through our management groups instead of at the subscription level. Basically we don't want access to be able to be assigned per subscription and want to block that capability. This way we are forced to grant access at the Management Group level instead.

Is there any way to do this, maybe via a Policy somehow?

Thanks for the helping!

Comment: A similar question answered in QnA. Please refer to this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/77899/force-all-azure-access-through-management-groups.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the answer from QnA for other communities reference (it seems the question in QnA is also asked by same OP).

> Currently it is not possible and we can submit a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback)